# Postgres on HDD Partition guide

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu-14.04

I am trying to reproduce the following

```
/
/var
/usr
/tmp
/home
[PGDATA]
[PGDATA]pg-xlog
[PGDATA]base
[PGDATA] / [tablespace]
[PGDATA] xlog-archive
```

but i'm a bit confuse with [PGDATA], i'm using Virtual host Ubuntu server 14.04 and i'm stuck in partition HDD stage. any references to read about this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: $PGDATA (or [PGDATA] in your case) is the directory in which the PostgreSQL installation lives. By default, everything in a database cluster is under this directory.

Comment: That said, is there a specific reason you create different partitions?

Comment: Thanks for your time , I attach 2 HDD with LVM and made a logical disk called PGDATA . Thanks you, now I understand [ PGDATA ] and $ PGDATA is the same thing and that confused me . So you mean I can install with apt -get Postgres then tell the system which are my directories to use?

Comment: By default, the $PGDATA goes into /var/lib/postgresql, but you can of course initialize your own cluster somewhere else. What I'm really asking is, why you specify different partitions for /var, /usr, /tmp and such. Is there a specific reason? If not, you might as well skip this and have one big partition and save you some trouble later on.